# XSLT for cut from one attribute and paste into another xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, attributes

I have to do XML to XML transformation for incoming request.
Below is the snippet of the sample XML

**Sample XML**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <OrderCreate Version="2.0.2">
        <OrderCreateBody xmlns="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OrderCreateDetails>
                <OrderCreateProductLineItem>
                    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                    <PurchaseOrderLineItemNumber>1</PurchaseOrderLineItemNumber>
                    <ProductIdentification>
                        <ProductIdentifier Agency="AssignedByManufacturer">11100668</ProductIdentifier>
                        <ProductName>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductName>
                        <ProductDescription>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductDescription>
                    </ProductIdentification>
                    <ProductQuantity>
                        <Measurement>
                            <MeasurementValue>6</MeasurementValue>
                            <UnitOfMeasureCode Domain="UN-Rec-20">EA</UnitOfMeasureCode>
                        </Measurement>
                    </ProductQuantity>
                    <ScheduleDateTimeInformation ScheduleType="RequestedDelivery">
                        <DateTimeInformation>
                            <DateTime DateTimeQualifier="On">20141201000000</DateTime>
                        </DateTimeInformation>
                    </ScheduleDateTimeInformation>
                </OrderCreateProductLineItem>
            </OrderCreateDetails>
        </OrderCreateBody>
    </OrderCreate>
</soapenv:Body>
```

For the above XML I need to **change this value**

```
    <ProductIdentification>
    <ProductIdentifier Agency="AssignedByManufacturer">11100668</ProductIdentifier>
    <ProductName>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductName>
    <ProductDescription>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductDescription>
</ProductIdentification>
```

**To this value**

```
<ProductIdentification Agency="AssignedByManufacturer">
<ProductIdentifier>11100668</ProductIdentifier>
<ProductName>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductName>
<ProductDescription>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductDescription>
<ProductGradeDescription/>
<ProductClassification/>
```

Below is the XSL I tried, but not working.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='OrderCreate']/*[local-name()='OrderCreateBody']/*[local-name()='OrderCreateDetails']/*[local-name()='OrderCreateProductLineItem']/*[local-name()='ProductIdentification']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='OrderCreate']/*[local-name()='OrderCreateBody']/*[local-name()='OrderCreateDetails']/*[local-name()='OrderCreateProductLineItem']/*[local-name()='ProductIdentification']/*[local-name()='ProductIdentifier']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ProductIdentifier">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The way I am doing it is wrong because I am not getting the desire output. Can anyone point me please right way to approach this problem?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you can't use the namespaces of the source XML and avoid the awkward *[local-name()='xyz'] type of reference?

Comment: @michael.hor257k most of the time what namespace partner are sending I don't have the control. So most of the time I go with [local-name()='abc']

Comment: You don't need to have control; you only need to have knowledge. Do they **change** the namespace URI without notice?

Comment: @michael They don't change the namespace URI.

Comment: The reason my solution didn't work was probably because I forgot the namespaces. I've recently come on here to try and help a few folks but if the reaction is to downvote anything but a complete solution handed on a plate well.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the namespace URI that the source XML is using, then the best way is to declare it in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing the nodes in the source XML:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ces="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ces:ProductIdentification">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ces:ProductIdentifier/@Agency"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ces:ProductIdentifier/@Agency"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This returns the following result (fragment):

```
...
<ProductIdentification Agency="AssignedByManufacturer">
    <ProductIdentifier>11100668</ProductIdentifier>
    <ProductName>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductName>
    <ProductDescription>ACCELERON INSEC-FUNG 15GA</ProductDescription>
</ProductIdentification>
...
```

I don't see where the `<ProductGradeDescription/>` shown in your requested result should come from.

---

### Edit:

> How can we add those elements by just directly declaring it?

You can just write it directly to the output tree - but if you want it to be in the same namespace as its parent and siblings, you must put it there either as:

```
<xsl:template match="ces:ProductIdentification">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ces:ProductIdentifier/@Agency"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <ces:ProductGradeDescription/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or:

```
<xsl:template match="ces:ProductIdentification">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ces:ProductIdentifier/@Agency"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <ProductGradeDescription xmlns="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt responses. I just looked at complete desire output.<ProductGradeDescription/> <ProductClassification/> are getting added. How can we add those elements by just directly declaring it?